# Changing external exe icon at runtime

Tags: c#, .net

I'm developing a simple application which is supposed to simply copy another existing executable file and **change it's icon**. Is this possible to achieve with .NET? I'm asking about icon changing, copying is not a problem.

I have no clues on how and where to start. I've searched on Google, but found only unmanaged C++ code which I'm not very much familiar with.

This post has nothing with changing current application's icon at runtime, rather it's about **changing the icon of an external application** (that's visible in Windows Explorer).

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

.NET has no support for this whatsoever.  The icon is stored in the unmanaged resources embedded in a .exe.  You can see them with File + Open + File, select the .exe and open the Icons node.  The lowest numbered icon is the one Windows uses.

Updating those resources normally requires rebuilding the .exe.  Luckily the Windows API has support for updating resources on-the-fly.  It has restrictions but that shouldn't affect you for icons.  You'll need BeginUpdateResource, UpdateResource and EndUpdateResource.  Beware that they are *not* easy to use, you need to know the icon resource number.  Visit pinvoke.net for the declarations you will need.

Answer (score -4):

'm assuming that you're using Visual Studio/Visual C# Express Edition.

To do this, try going to Project > Your App Properties. On the Application tab, change the Icon dropdown box to whatever icon you please.

Comment: That has nothing to do with this question, he is trying to get his program to change the icon of another program. Not try and change the icon of his own program. He even explicitly says that in his question "*This post has nothing with changing current application's icon at runtime, rather it's about **changing the icon of an external application** (that's visible in Windows Explorer).*" Please edit your answer to be on topic or delete it.